# Android - Bug in Webview? Some URL's prompt webview to start external browser

Tags: android, url, webview

I have a "NewsActivity" with a webview. When I start it from my main activity, links are opened in the webview correctly but, for some reason, some url's cause the webview to open but then to immediately launch the external browser. Checking the debug console I have not found any exception or other message thrown by webview as not being able to handle the url.
Please note that I am not talking about a link clicked after the webview has loaded the url/page.
I have also tried to activate javascript in the webview but to no avail.
Also, this happens for just some urls  from the same domain (specifically a news website; also, I have no block url or override in place).

Here is one of the urls that fail to open in the webview: [url_not_loaded](http://elpais.com/ccaa/2014/08/05/catalunya/1407229715_303150.html)

Here is the code that calls the "NewsActivity"

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, url);
            startActivity(intent);
```

And here is the code in "NewsActivity"

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String url = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.newsv);
    Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "URL: " + url);
    mWebview.loadUrl(url);
}
```

If someone has a clue as to what may be happening or can suggest any idea, I'll be grateful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL's might have redirects.  I encountered a similar problem.

Add this to your activity with the webview.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
```

Add this outside of onCreate.

```
private class Callback extends WebViewClient{  //Helps to open in webview instead of browser

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return (false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what happened. The original url had a redirect, that's why it opened the browser at once. The only thing with this solution (which works fine otherwise) is that subsequent links are opened in the webview instead of being opened in the browser - which is what I wanted - but I guess this can't be avoided, as it is a matter of websites using redirects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**It's not a bug.**

You need to use [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html).

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            System.out.println("hello");
            return false;
        }
    });
    //Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a newWebViewClient like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

But to be more precisely you need to override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
  view.loadUrl(url);
  return true;
}});
```